# Does the (GPT) partition table location change when moving from USB3 to SATA?

Tags: external-hdd, gpt

I have just opened an external USB 3.0 hard disk enclosure and mounted the disk instead internally in a PC via SATA.  Now, the Linux system stops finding the GPT which was certainly there.  Since there are already 2 TB of data on the disk it would be nice to find the partition table which is already there.

Can the location of the GPT change when using a different interface (USB, SATA)?  How can it be fixed?

Here is the gdisk output mounted in the PC (SATA):

```
# gdisk /dev/disk/by-id/ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ABA300_123456890
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries.

Command (? for help): q
```

The disk is a TOSHIBA DT01ABA300 (as you can see above) and was in a Toshiba Canvio USB3 enclosure.

Here is the relevant portion of `dmesg`:

```
[    1.618441] scsi host9: ahci
[    1.618485] ata9: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m512@0xfd1ff000 port 0xfd1ff100 irq 42
[    2.106001] ata9: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    2.107329] ata9.00: ATA-8: TOSHIBA DT01ACA300, MX6OABB0, max UDMA/133
[    2.107332] ata9.00: 5860533168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.108712] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.609553] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      TOSHIBA DT01ABA3 ABB0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.609699] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[    2.609703] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    2.609785] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[    2.609788] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.609825] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.637653] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk
```

Here is where I found the EFI (GPT?!) signature on the raw disk:

```
dd if=/dev/sdg bs=2M count=32 | hexdump -C | grep -w EFI
32+0 records in
32+0 records out
67108864 bytes (67 MB) copied, 0.447864 s, 150 MB/s
00001000  45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54  00 00 01 00 5c 00 00 00  |EFI PART....\...|
```

I did not find a `gdisk` parameter to read the GPT from a particular offset.  How can I read it?

```
# parted /dev/sdg
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdg
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit b                                                           
(parted) print                                                            
Error: /dev/sdg: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ABA3 (scsi)                                        
Disk /dev/sdg: 3000592982016B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 
(parted) q
```

And:

```
# losetup --find --show /dev/sdg
/dev/loop0
# parted /dev/loop0
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/loop0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit b                                                           
(parted) print                                                            
Error: /dev/loop0: unrecognised disk label
Model: Loopback device (loopback)                                         
Disk /dev/loop0: 3000592982016B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 
(parted)
```

Comment: It definitely *shouldn't*, assuming of course that the enclosure is well-behaved...

Comment: That's what I hoped, but where has the partition gone?

Comment: Let's see the relevant portion of the partition scan output from the kernel initialization (use `dmesg | less`)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Done. Hope nothing is missing.  No partition output for this disk in `dmesg`.

Comment: Output of `parted /dev/disk unit b print` and `parted $(losetup --find --show /dev/disk) unit b print`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the location of the GPT change when using a different interface (USB, SATA)?

Yes, because GPT is stupid and depends on sector size, and some USB enclosures claim `512b` sectors when it's really `4096b` sectors or vice versa.

Yes, because Linux is stupid and does not support GPT for differing block sizes even though it should be possible to detect this automatically.

You might have to re-create the partition table to convert from GPT-512 to GPT-4096 and hope the partitions were MiB-aligned to allow such conversions in the first place.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I find and read the relevant sector (with the GPT) on the disk and open gdisk with the correct offset? (Partitions were MB-aligned, that will be no problem.)

Comment: Added location of GPT above, can I read it somehow (and write it to the correct location / re-create)?

Comment: Your GPT is using 4K sectors so if that does not work and no partitioning software is smart enough to understand it either, you somehow have to emulate a device with 4K sectors. If the enclosure is still available, easiest solution might be to just read the partition table from there.

Comment: I have three SATA controllers in my PC.  Could it be a different one will suppport the 4K feature of the disk?  (I would just try but rebooting takes ages...)

Comment: Regular sata controllers have no need to lie about sector sizes the way some USB enclosures do. A good partitioning software should be able to handle it, if it does not you could patch it to assume 4K sectors for 512b devices, just to get a read on partition byte offsets.

Comment: If you upload the first 64K of your disk somewhere I'd be happy to run some experiments. I currently have no (easy) way to replicate your issue...

Comment: As I can apparently find and dump the actual GPT (@1000h) I can also find the LBA of the partitions.  I will use this to re-create a GPT partition table with these numbers.  Remains the question: Do I need to translate the LBA numbers for it to work (my guess is no because these are sectors)?

Comment: @Ned64: Yes, you have to translate them by factor 8 since they will refer to 4K sectors and you need 512 byte sectors. You can test offsets with `losetup --offset bytes`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, read and copied the GPT, editing it now. The problem I currently have is that `gdisk` tells me the last usable sector is 732566639, which is rubbish. That number is from the GPT header. Apparently this cannot be changed with `gdisk`, so I may need to zap and re-create the GPT.

Comment: Done it!  First copied the old GPT (with 4k units) to the correct location, like so: `dd if=/dev/sdg bs=2M count=32 > sdg` then `dd if=sdg bs=256 skip=16 count=1 of=/dev/sdg seek=2` and `dd if=sdg bs=256 skip=32  count=1 of=/dev/sdg seek=4`.  Read contents of old GPT with `gdisk /dev/sdg`, wrote down all details (start/end/type of partitions), multiplied those 4k-addresses by 8 to get 512b-sectors, then zapped GPT by `dd if=/dev/zero bs=4k count=3 of=/dev/sdg`, then re-created new GPT with `gdisk /dev/sdg` and new addresses.  All data is still there :-)

Comment: @Ned64: No need to (and dangerous) to write this to the disk itself, you could've used a loop file, glad it worked out anyway, aaand this should work by default in Linux or at least be supported directly by gdisk, parted et al. Maybe you should write this in an answer rather than leaving it as a comment here.

Comment: Thanks, but I had the `dd` backup of the first 64 MB, which made me more daring :-)  I am a big fan of `dd` anyway.  I was thinking of editing your answer but I may write it up properly again when I have the time, good idea.